# What slicing do in the list?

Tags: python, list, slice, numpy-slicing

```
a = '1234'
print a[3:0:-1]
```

Output: 432

In slicing we know that list[start:stop:step]
In the output how come '32' comes.
I believe -1 gives len(list)-1 but if that is the case then how come its '32'
Your suggestions will be helpful thanks

Comment: The `step=-1` here means that list will be traversed in reverse.

Answer (score 0):

the trick here is `-1`

```
a = '1234'
print a[3:0:-1]
```

the following code mean start from a[3] = 4 and decrease -1 until you arrive to a[0] = 1 but don't print a[0]